# Is it worthwhile to retake the GRE (math) subject test?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre

I took the math subject test recently and conservatively speaking I think my score range is mid 60s-mid/high 70s percentile, although it is hard to say for sure. My biggest problem was running out of time towards the end; I'm usually not a fast test taker since I like to take my time and think through the problems (I know this is not recommended for a standardized test like the GRE, but old habits are hard to break). As a result I don't think I scored as well as I could have (or at least my score doesn't reflect my abilities accurately). I'm wondering if I should re-take the exam (the next testing date, and the only one before applications are due, is October 24th. This is before I will have received my test scores from September).

On the one hand, I think and hope that more practice will lead to a more desirable score. But on the other hand, I would rather spend my time (and not spend my money) on more interesting things like my classes and my honors thesis. I have also heard that taking the test twice may actually not be so great since if I don't score significantly better (or if I score worse) on the second try, it will reflect negatively on my application.

A bit about myself for context: My interests are in algebra/NT; however, I'd like to go to a school with a large grad program so I can be flexible in case I decide to change my research focus. I have a good deal of research experience (2 summers at REUs with results from one published, and the other in preparation for publication. Also I have done and am currently doing work with two professors from my undergraduate institution). I believe I have strong letters; my grades are good and I've been taking challenging courses (currently in some grad classes). The schools I've thought about applying to (but have not finalized on) are: BC (very small program but close to home and I like the faculty), BU, MIT, UCLA, UWisconsin-Madison.

My questions are:

1. Are the GRE scores important enough that I should re-take it?
2. Or should I commit myself to other components of the application like grades/purpose letters?
3. What are the range of schools that my (supposed) scores will be acceptable at (taking into consideration the other parts of my application as well)?

Any other advice or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you can select which score to share, and not reveal the fact that you took it twice -- but this can be checked with the folks who administer the exam.  //  In terms of the best use of your time -- based on your exposition, it sounds like it wouldn't be a bad idea to sit the exam once more, to try a different time management strategy -- but between now and the exam date, probably best not to spend any time preparing, but rather focus on other aspects of your applications, as you said.